# Using class variable for type hinting in __init__

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

In Python, I have a list of "allowed types" in my class, and in the constructor I would like to pass an argument that has to be in that list of allowed types. So, conceptually, this is what I would like:

```
from typing import Union

class A:
  allowed_types = [typeA, typeB]

  def __init__(self, some_argument: Union[allowed_types]):
     (do stuff)
```

I'm not sure how to tackle this. How would you set something like this up? Maybe there's a better set-up for this, but I'm not sure how. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use this in your in your constructor:

```
for element in some_argument:
    # This will throw an error if the type is not in the approved types.
    assert type(element) in approved_types
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you're on Python3.9+ it is recommended to use the native types instead of the typing types. (eg: list > typing.List, set > typing.Set)

Second, on Python 3.10+ you can do Type1 | Type2 for unions which is a lot better. So for type hints: def func(var: Type1 | Type2)

Thirdly, if you can take in multiple types, take a second to think about your application. Are those types related? Maybe they should be inherited? If you have for example allowed_types = [TaxCalc, AmortCalc], maybe your types should have a common parent BaseCalc or CalcInterface which you can pass as the type hint. Otherwise check how I did it above

To actually answer, I'd personall;y just create the union as a type and then pass it. But idk why you want it in your class. Usually I make my custom type definitions in a file and import from there.

For example, I have in most projects a file called "type_extensions.py" which looks something like this:

```
Number_t = int | float | complex
String_t = str | bytes
```

Here's one: https://github.com/zkscpqm/python-common/blob/master/types_extensions.py

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make sure some_argument is an instance of a list of specific types you could do something like this:

```
class A:
    allowed_types = [int,float]

    def __init__(self,some_argument):
        if type(some_argument) in self.allowed_types:
            self.some_argument = some_argument
        else:
            raise TypeError("some_argument must be of type {}".format(self.allowed_types))

# raise a TypeError if some_argument is not of type int or float
A("1")
```